# How to iterate over json data in react native

Tags: json, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

```
data={"OEfxVtMSnLNtvmX8Sv1qgnoHwLX2": {"FirstName": "pradeep", 
"Gender":"Male", "LastName": "PRADEep", "MobileNo": "903XXXXXXXXX"}}
```

HOw to iterate over this in react native ?

Comment: You want to access the FirstName and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch keys and than iterate it to get the data as below

```js
const datas = {
    OEfxVtMSnLNtvmX8Sv1qgnoHwLX2: {
        FirstName: "pradeep",
        Gender: "Male",
        LastName: "PRADEep",
        MobileNo: "903XXXXXXXXX"
    }
};
const keys = Object.keys(datas);
for (let data of keys) {
    for (let innerKey in datas[data]) {
        console.log(innerKey, datas[data][innerKey]);
    }
}
```